# How to do a proper revert in TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs

So recently I managed to break our entire project (at least on my laptop) with a naive NuGet package installation. Thinking that our CVS is basically Git, I go around looking for a way to do the GUI equivalent of "git checkout -whatever was before things were messed up-"

After much digging and asking, I find an undo button. Naive I use undo on the solution hoping this would at least restore me prior to all the changes I made. Somehow this breaks the project even more.

It feels ridiculous that it should be this difficult. I mean its one small line on a console.

I know our GitHub repository. Is there anyway to clean out the entire project on my laptop and run the equivalent of 'git clone' on it, without somehow messing up that repository? I'm kinda scared that my TFS might be acting clever and updating the repository in responses to what I'd be doing.

**Update**

It turns out it might just be Git on Visual Studio. If that's the case then fixing things should be simple. I need to know two things 1) How do I clone a project. 2) How do I open a text-prompt where I can enter commands like 'git checkout', 'git branch' etc... and have them work on my solution?

Comment: I mean all I want is to make my code, packages, everything, identical to the master branch we have on GitHub.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  In your title you mention TFS, and later you mention that you are using GitHub.  Which one is it?  Perhaps it would help if you clarify the exact problem that you are having.

Comment: I'm one of two developers, very new who was asked to continue work on a website by our boss. Its a C#, Umbraco, MVC thing in Visual Studio... it was made in three months by a former intern, and its a mess.

When I click 'Team Explorer'. Local Git Repositories (so I assume its not TFS anyway?) I see four buttons 'Changes', 'Branches', 'Sync', 'Settings'

Comment: Clicking 'Branches' gives me the local branch, and the remotes, but so far no way to do checkouts or anything.

Comment: So it might just be git actually... is there any way to just get a text-prompt where I can type in stuff like 'git log', 'git checkout', 'get merge' etc...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to find out where your repository version controlled, GitHub or TFS.

If the repository is version controlled by TFS, check the steps below to clone your repo:

1. You need permission to access the repository (contact your administrator to grant your permission).
2. Connect to TFS in Team Explorer

   [image]
3. If you haven't cloned the repo on the machine you use, "Clone this repository" will be prompted. Just clone it on your machine:

   [image]

   If the machine you use have cloned the repo before, you'll see the repo under Solutions section in Team Explorer. Just double click it:

   [image]

Then you can work on the repo and make version control with TFS.

Of course you can use command line to clone the repo too. You can clone a repository with `git clone [url]`. You need specify the URL the repo stored, and the sign in windows will be prompted if the URL requires logon.